# text,button and backround fits at all android devices

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-flamingo

I am a beginner in android studio, I'm practicing developing simple app using android studio flamingo.
my problem is , how can I manage my app so that whatever text, button or background image I put, it automatically manages itself the same way I put it in code. I'm having difficulty to manage all text , buttons and background image to fit all the phones same way
kindly help
using windows 10 x64 , Kotlin , android studio flamingo.
thanks

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:background="@drawable/practice"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


  <Button
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:elevation="14dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="button 1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:translationY="30dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:fontFamily="@font/abeezee"
    android:text="button 2"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:translationY="40dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/alata"
    android:text="MAIN SCREEN"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#CDDC39"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:translationY="-310dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/alata"
    android:text="PROTECTOR"
    android:textColor="#8BC34A"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:translationX="0dp"
    android:translationY="-410dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/alata"
    android:text="SELECT ANY ONE"
    android:textColor="#00BCD4"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:translationY="-340dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/alata"
    android:text="protect"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="#8BC34A"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:translationY="140dp" />
```

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lSQcJjZPFs

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to make your widgets fit any screen and flexable on every device.
Consider Using **Constraint Layout**

see this awesome guide: **[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout)**

another guide: **[ConstraintLayout](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/getting-started-with-constraint-layout-in-android/)**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).